# Whatsapp says "Your phone date is inaccurate", but this isn't true

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I can't log on to Whatsapp on my new phone because as soon as I open the app, I get this message:

> **Your phone date is inaccurate! Adjust your clock and try again**.
>
> Your phone date and time is: 16:08, 6/22/2016 (Greenwich Mean Time)
>
> [Adjust date]

The only option is to go to the Date and Time settings (or cancel with the back button).

Trouble is, my date and time are **correct**. They're set to...

> **Automatic.** Use network-provided values

...and those values match my timezone and the time Google and other sources give to my timezone.

What can I do about this erroneous error?

I've got a stable connection, this is a low-spec duel sim phone running 4.1.1, with Whatsapp pre-installed.

Whatsapp recently (10 minutes ago) updated itself. Settings > Manage Applications tells me it's on version 2.11.448.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling- helped me the only time I had this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forcing Whatsapp to update through Google Play (uninstalling previous updates if necessary) seems to have fixed this.

It sounds like this is a common problem and is most often caused by a version issue, despite the misleading message ([example source](https://www.roidbay.com/blog/guide/fixed-phone-date-inaccurate-whatsapp/)).